# Redirect SharePoint site address (doc library) to another URL

Tags: powershell, redirect, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Anybody knows how to redirect a document library to another url.

example:

This url:
https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test-a/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Should be redirected to:
https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test-b/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I have tried in SharePoint designer and Powershell but cannot find a solution.

Anybody an idea how to do this?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

If the library is using the Classic interface, you can edit the page and insert a Custom HTML web part that has 1 line of javascript that redirects the window.location.href

Comment: If I go to edit the page, I get can insert a HTML form webpart but I cant insert any code here. I can also add a content editor and then I can edit the source in HTML but I guess this is not the HTMl of the site.

Comment: You should be able to set the Source location of the web part. Using SP Designer you can store an htm file in a library and then reference the file url:  `/sites/test-a/siteassets/redirect.htm`. Inside that file, add a script tag and it'll be included inline on the page. something like this should work: `<script>window.location.href='/site-b/'`;</script>`